# Any ppt(x) to html converter (php, debian server)?

Tags: php, html, powerpoint

I use [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) for converting one document format to another. But OpenOffice (unoconv based on it) can't convert ppt(x) to html.

Does anybody know useful libraries or something else for doing this? Project hosted on Debian, language is php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact OpenOffice (and unoconv as a result) can convert PPT and PPTX files to HTML.

Tested with unoconv 0.4 and OpenOffice 3.2.1.

Comment: Looks like I have used 2.x version of OpenOffice. Thank you. I'll try to use 3.x

Answer (score 0):

[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I don't see how the OP can grab the library with just "the essential parts of the answer" if the link is broken. I highly doubt the linked page will change; it may become deprecated, but I doubt it'll change.